# Apk failed to build in debug Mode after changing my windows and ssd

Tags: flutter, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKsOR.jpg)

This project is working fine but after installing SSD in my laptop i faced this problem problem inside Screen Shot

And even if i create a dummy new project for testing then also this will create this problem when i click f5 in my laptop basically when i want to create a new project

I try to reinstall my SDK and re allocate variable paths but still not fixed

I want to fix this error without fixing i don't even run my any other project even new project also.

Comment: hey, do not put a screenshot of your error, you should write your error down.